# Ruby on Rails, calling a very big method from a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a very big function in my model and I want to store it somewhere else in order to keep my model dry. I read that storing methods in ApplicationHelper and then calling them from a model is a bad idea. What is a good idea then?
I want to have a separate file with my big methods and call them from a model.

Comment: "DRY" has nothing to do with the size of methods, it has to do with not repeating artifacts. "Big" methods are a smell: methods should be decomposed into concise, focused units. How to proceed in your particular case depends more on what you're actually doing than on the size of the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Concern. https://gist.github.com/1014971

It's simple. In `app/models/concerns` create a file `your_functionality.rb` as follows:

```
module YourFunctionality
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def your_fat_method
    # insert...
  end
end
```

And in your model simply:

```
include YourFunctionality
```

Comment: Modules are nice, but this method is still 100% part of the class. It might appear to be outside of the class, but by including it you haven't achieved any separation.

Comment: Put a fat model on diet. Exactly this is what the solution does, and it is the rails way to achieve this currently. Its an very easy, leightweight and understandable pattern. See DHH's posts about this stuff.Don't see any reason for downvoting.

Comment: FWIW, I didn't downvote your answer. However, without reusing this module, the model is not on a diet.

Comment: Concerns can be shared across models. It's up to the Coder how to use this mechanic. You may even decide to inclue the module only under specific circumstances. Thus said, it is not important to "reduce" the model at runtime but separate it in logical chunks for better reading. If you want an idealistic solution, have fun with the DCI stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a "plain old ruby object (PORO)" to do your work for you. let's say you had a method that calculates the amount overdue for a user.

So, you can create app/services/calculates_overages.rb

```
class CalculatesOverages
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def calculate
    # your method goes here
  end
end
```

Then, you can:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def overage_amount
    CaluclatesOverage.new(self).calculate
  end
end
```

Or, in a controller you could:

```
def show
  @amount = CaluclatesOverage.new(current_user).calculate
end
```

The app/services directory could also be app/models, or the lib directory. There's no set convention for this (yet).

Comment: m...sorry, I am a bit new to ruby on rails. I need to pass to my method just a list of some words, so I do not have to initialize it. How should it work then?

Comment: @Katja The same way, but with no `initialize` method.

Comment: looks like a good sample for a rails3 `concern`. It is not only useful for shared functionality, but also to set fat models on diet.

Comment: CaluclatesOverage.new(self).calculate shouldn't it be modified then?

Comment: @Katja yes, if you're just passing words, it would be `CalculatesOverages.new.calculate(words)`